# Why does vscode pylint miss obvious errors?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint

I have a python file open in Visual Studio Code with an obvious error (using an undefined variable) but the pylint issues listed under 'Problems' show only a long list of minor convention issues.

Running pylint manually on it (separately from vscode) spots the error fine. The error is not explicitly excluded by any vscode pylint-related configs as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I discovered this was due to the following default setting in vscode:

```
"python.linting.maxNumberOfProblems": 100
```

Editing this config to a higher number (e.g. 1000) made the error show up.

Evidently this limit is applied blindly to the pylint output in the order the problems are found, so if enough minor issues precede an error then the error will be hidden - not ideal.