# How to check variable naming typos in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have some code with a variable named "angle". However in the loop I mistakenly wrote "angla".

My question is, how might I make VS code warn me about this? Some IDEs, like PyCharm, warn me of the mistake.

```
... 
for line in open("data.txt", "r"):
    ...
    angle_a = atan2(Vya, Vxa)
    angle_b = atan2(Vyb, Vxb)
    while t <= 10:
        Pa, Va_mag, angle_a, Va = motion(
            Pa, Va_mag, angle_a, Va)  
        Pb, Vb_mag, angle_b, Vb = motion(
            Pb, Vb_mag, angle_b, Vb)  
        if collision_test(Pa, Pb) == True: 
            Va, Vb = after_collision_velocity(Va, Vb, Pa, Pb)
            Va_mag = vec_magnitude(Va)  
            Vb_mag = vec_magnitude(Vb)
            angla_a = atan2(Va[1], Va[0]) # here is the mistake
            angle_b = atan2(Vb[1], Vb[0])
        t += dt 
...
```

Is there any way VS code could give me an error when something like this happens? Any helpful extensions, spell-checkers, AI-IntelliSense, etc? (Python-specific)

Comment: If there are lots of other errors/warnings in the code, this might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861276/why-does-vscode-pylint-miss-obvious-errors

Comment: There was no other error.

Comment: First ask yourself this question - how do you presume VS code to know `angla_a` is a typo of `angle_a` and not a new object as your code indicates? Consider this - should VS code also warn you when you introduce `angle_c` like "did you mean `angle_b`?" IMO unfortunately this is one of those scenarios you just need to be careful, because it is a valid syntax, just creating a new object.

Comment: @Roca it gives an error in PyCharm

Comment: It wouldn't give you an error if it were `angel_a`.  It's just a spelling check, which there are plenty spell checker extension on the VS Code extension market.  But if you actually wanted to check for objects being referenced correctly that's a different story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code's marketplace has extensions that may help you preemptively identify these types of errors.

I am not sure about post-error detection, but Microsoft's Visual Studio **IntelliCode** will suggest the correct variable names before you begin making a typing mistake.

[Visual Studio IntelliCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode)

**There is also a Python-specific extension at:**

[Python Extension - With  IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)

**IntelliSense In Action:**

[IntelliSense ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akbCw.jpg)

Comment: After installing the extensions (try both), make sure to restart your VS Code client.  I have added a screenshot of IntelliSense suggesting the correct variable declaration.

Comment: I see now. That is open.. indeed. But suppose you even made a typo in that condition

Comment: Right, IntelliSense just tries to help you avoid the mistake.  I'm not sure you could detect the typo in your situation, especially because it looks like any other variable declaration.  Maybe, if you suspect a typo, try using ctrl+f (find all) to investigate the situation.